# MAMP Pro Error: The MySQL configuration file my.cnf couldn't be written

Tags: mysql, macos, mamp, virtualhost

I tried to use MAMP Pro to replace previous XAMPP on my Mac due to its easy Virtual Hosts management. However after I installed it. The MAMP, basic version works, but the Pro version keeps given me this error message:

The MySQL configuration file my.cnf couldn't be written.

I googled for a while and there are some different solutions, like create my.cnf on /etc/, but none of these works. Also the error log is empty.

Has someone encountered this before? Or does anyone have a clue how could I solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: I'm having the same problem. MAMP PRO just gives this error right after a fresh install. I have tried resetting to factory settings, which didn't fix it, and neither did creating a my.cnf or copying one of the templates to etc (and other folders) under the name my.cnf.

Comment: It appears that the issue was with the new MAMP PRO update to version 2.1.3, which they have retracted. Version [2.1.2](http://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/index.html) has been made available, which works just fine as it used to. 2.1.4, which has the new features and also fixes the issue entirely, will be made available shortly, according to [this post in the MAMP forums](http://forum.mamp.info/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=85804#p104016). In short, [download and install version 2.1.2](http://www.mamp.info/downloads/releases/MAMP_MAMP_PRO_2.1.2.zip) to fix the issue right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just purchased MAMP PRO and I'm having this error as well. Here's what "fixed" it:

1. Open Terminal and type in `sudo killall -9 mysqld`. You might see "No matching processes belonging to you were found," which is fine, it means that MySQL was not running.
2. Now, in Applications, look for the regular MAMP folder. Open MAMP here and click **Start Servers**
3. Now open MAMP PRO and the servers should be started

This is just a work-around, it definitely should not require these. At the very least, this should get you up and running.

Contacting support!

Comment: This workaround does the trick! Great solution. I would like to mention that your first step could benefit from a little `sudo`, in case the system doesn't fully agree with you killing all MySQL processes: `sudo killall -9 mysqld`.

Comment: I should mention ... appsolute wrote me back about the ticket I filed and said that they are working on a fix for this.

Comment: This is not working for me with OS X 10.9.1 and MAMP PRO 2.2. Are there any new discoveries?

Answer (score 2):

File -> Reset to Factory Settings

Possibly a permissions issue, but I wasn't able to resolve it. The above fixed it for me.

Comment: Me 2, I still get the same error. BTW, did you install other similar program before use MAMP? Like XAMPP?

Comment: I'm receiving this error on a fresh install on a brand new install of OS X 10.7.5

Answer (score 1):

1. uninstall mamp.
2. remove all files about mamp.
3. reinstall mamp.

Answer (score 0):

I removed 'my.cnf' from '/etc' directory. Restarted MAMP pro. Started server successfully.....

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration may be wrong.

exp.

```
sql_mode = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION # success
```

or

```
sql_mode = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION' # error
```